# Using Try::Tiny and $_ to get "the type of error"

Tags: perl

I wrote the following method for getting a log error. I use $_ to get "the type of error".

```
sub _log_warning {
    my $log = Log::Server->new(
        base_dir =>
          &config->current->{'log_reader'}->{'base_dir'},
        pattern => &config->current->{'log_reader'}->{'pattern'},
    );
    $log->infof("Could not register to DB. Got $_");
}
```

because I saw $_ is used for getting what type of error was produced.
I used this in this context:

```
 use Try::Tiny;
 try { _log_to_database(); }
 catch {
     _log_warning();
 };
```

Is this Ok syntatically? I expect _log_warning(); to do a log of the error, and $_ should say the type of error that happen. But maybe i'm not using $_ well?

Update:

When I tried to produce an error, to active the method, I got:

```
 2013-07-04T11:15:56 [INFO] Could not register to DB. Got ã<81><9d>ã<81>®ã<82><88>ã<81>     <86>ã<81>ªã<83><95>ã<82>¡ã<82>¤ã<83>«ã<82><84>ã<83><87>ã<82>£ã<83>¬ã<82>¯ã<83><88>ã<83>>> ªã<81>¯ã<81><82>ã<82><8a>ã<81>¾ã<81><9b>ã<82><93>: /var/log/app.error.log.%Y%m%d at script.pl line 36.\n at script.pl line 113
```

:(

@ikegami SOS

Comment: What do you expect it to do? And is it doing that?

Comment: @Flimzy I expect $_ to catch the type of error. Syntactic error, etc..?

Answer (score 1):

So according the [`Try::Tiny`](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Try-Tiny-0.12/lib/Try/Tiny.pm) document:

> Inside the catch block the caught error is stored in $_, while previous value of $@ is still available for use.

So this module will set `$_` to the error that was caught, so your use looks correct. This is interesting [blog post](http://blog.woobling.org/2009/09/trytiny.html) going logic behind the design.

Comment: thanks! But i dont explain myself why the " ã<81><9d>ã<81>®ã<82><88>ã<81>" message showed up

Comment: @adriancdperu `_log_to_database()` is generating an error, the message is coming from there, so you need to track down the source to understand the error better.

Comment: yes the error catching process is ok. In stdout it gives me the error message "the file does not exist" in Japanese. So, its an enconding problem. Somehow, when I put the error as a log in a folder, it does not recognize the Japanese and gives me the weird symbols instead.

Comment: @adriancdperu These articles may potentially help http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=913179 and http://perlgeek.de/en/article/encodings-and-unicode but you might want to post a separate question on encoding issues if they don't